# xamarin forms apk file can't open in chrome downloads

Tags: android, google-chrome, xamarin.forms, apk

I have published an adhok apk file using xamarin forms, but when I download the app using chrome browser, it says "can't open the file"! I don't have the issue with other browsers, only chrome and my users mostly use chrome browser, does anybody know how to solve this problem?